# is ListView.Items order caused by Index of ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have several `ListViewItems` i want to order it in different way using its `Index`. Is it possible that when i change index of item and the item location in `ListView`  will be affected ?

Comment: This question was closed because it's a poor question.  There's no context, no code, and it's not written well. That's why it was closed as 'not a real question'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ListViewItem.Index Property` to order items (besides, its read-only). Instead use the [ListView.Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.sort.aspx).

**EDIT:** For **WPF**, see http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=24

Comment: ahh, really forget about it, with this Sort method, i can do everything about sorting ?

Comment: i see now, that this method is for Forms. But i mentioned that i use WPF